# N Panel tabs sidebar to fill vertically

Tags: interface, add-on, panel

In Blender 3.5 my many add-on tabs in the N-Panel sidebar filled the vertical space (reducing the names/labels of each tab to fit). Upgrading to 3.6 it seems this is no longer a feature and the tabs now scroll vertically to display them.

Any suggestions for how to have the tabs fill the vertical space?

Comment: I don't think that it's possible. [This](https://archive.blender.org/developer/D15395) is the (long) developer discussion about the change.